# Windows Azure CDN with new management portal

Tags: azure

How to find the Windows Azure CDN with new managment portal. To be noted i am using the Preview portal and in 90 days free trial

Answer (score 9):

I contacted MS Support about this, since old portal link is no longer available.

Here is the reply as of Sep 26, 2013:

> We’re in the process of building out our next generation Windows Azure
>   Content Delivery Network (CDN) architecture, and during this time we
>   are no longer accepting new CDN customers. With the CDN functionality
>   having recently transitioned to the new Azure management portal, we
>   have enabled it automatically only for customers who were using CDN in
>   the old management portal, so they can continue to manage their CDN
>   configurations. For everyone else, the CDN feature is not enabled in
>   the new portal. We highly encourage you to wait until we’re ready
>   building our next generation Azure CDN service.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can ask the rep to get you into the CDN, although I wouldn't recommend it as it is a pretty involved process and they will request a lot of information.  CloudFront will work well in most cases for you to get your CDN up and running and you can then switch it over to Azure when their new version is up.

Answer (score 2):

From the Preview Portal mouse over the green preview link at the top and click on the link, "Take me to the previous portal". Then on the left, click on Hosted Services, Storage Accounts & CDN.

From there you must create a Storage Account if you don't already have one. If you do, select CDN from the left menu. Once there, select your desired Storage Account, and click the New Endpoint button from the top nav. Check the box for Enable CDN and click OK.

Answer (score 2):

For now you need to access the previous portal which you can find by clicking in the Top-Right corner (where your email is shown) and the Avatar Bar will be displayed with an option to go to "Previous Portal"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that feature is not in the new Portal. You will have to use the old (Silverlight) portal.